# How to erase photos from my iPhone 5S?

Tags: photos, iphone

I am syncing my iPhone 5S with my iMac. In iTunes it tells me I am over my 64 GB allowable memory with the majority of the space being used for over 4000 photos.

How do I delete the photos from my iPhone? I would like to keep photos taken in this year.

Comment: Import them via iPhoto, and remove the pictures you don't want anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Plug device into Mac. Open Image Capture (in the *Applications* folder), select device in sidebar. Check the option at the bottom that says "delete on import" then import all files to the selected folder or program.

I used to do this manually, only deleting older photos, but with the iCloud Photo Stream, you will always have the last 1000 pictures available, so there's no reason not to just delete all after import.

You may end up with duplicate photos. There are several tools you can use to resolve dupes. Personally, I dump all imported photos into a specific directory, then run a dupe resolver, then add the new images into my photo management programs. (Not an iPhoto user because it doesn't sync well between Macs. Don't know if it has any in-built dupe resolution. YMMV.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have iPhoto installed on your iPhone 5s, then you can do a "select all" of the photos you want to delete - or you can connect your iPhone to a Mac, and then via **Image Capture** select the photos to delete.

If your iMac is the master, then you can re-sync the photos taken in this year to your iPhone again, if you have deleted all.